# Remove line feed(s) from start of specific files

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I need to remove any occurrences of line feeds (carriage returns on a mac) from the very start of all files with the .php or .html extension. There are *no* other characters between the line feeds like spaces or anything.

So for example (using /lf as an example of line feed):

```
/lf
/lf
<!doctype html>
```

or

```
/lf
<!doctype html>
```

should be reduced down to:

```
<!doctype html>
```

One way of removing line feeds I've found is:

```
tr -d '\012'
```

But I have no idea how to target this at specific files, let alone only the first few lines.

So I've got the following:

```
find . \( -name "*.php" -or -name "*.html" \) | xargs grep -l "\012" | xargs sed -i -e "s/\012//g"
```

But this won't target only the first few lines, and I'm not entirely sure if it correctly targets line feeds either.

So, anyone got any bright ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i '/./,$\!d' filename
```

or even from find:

```
find . \( -name "*.php" -or -name "*.html" \) -exec sed -i '/./,$\!d' {} \;
```

---

EDIT:

The `\` before the `!d` may not be needed, in my shell I need to escape it because csh keeps thinking I'm referring to a previous event via the `!` symbol.

---

EDIT 2:

So the `/./,$\!d`, bit, it looks like gibberish but this is what's happening.

1. There are 2 addresses being defined here, the first is the regex `.` which is anything that isn't a blank line. Thus the first address is the first non-blank line matched by `/./`.
2. Then we have the second address, separated by the `,`, and it's simply `$`, the end of the file. So the region we've defined by our 2 addresses is the first non-blank line all the way to the end of the file.
3. We're going to use sed's **delete** function here, which is denoted by the last `d` in the script. However, by using `d`, we'd be deleting everything starting from the first non-blank line to the end of the file.
4. Lastly, because we'd be deleting the very thing that we want, we use a `!` right in front of the `d` command to tell sed, "ok, do exactly the opposite of what I'm telling you to do instead". Thus, instead of deleting everything starting from the first non-blank line to the end of the file, we're doing the complete opposite, preserving the first non-blank line to the end of the file, which has the effect of deleting all of the blank lines at the beginning of the file.

There's probably some way to do this using the `p` (print) command, which is *sort of like* the opposite of delete, but doesn't really behave that way. I'm sure there's some way to do this using `p` or `!p`.

Comment: Could you please explain what the expression '/./,$\!d' means?

Comment: I created a testfile with: `seq 4 | sed '1s/.*/\n/; 2s/.*/\n\r/; 3s/.*/\r/; 4s/.*/<!doctype html>/'`. Here `sed '/[[:blank:]]/,$!d'` works better.

Comment: @BrunovonParis Edited the answer with a detailed explanation of the gibberish.

Comment: And to create backups in case it doesn't work as intended, I simply add a character to -i (so -i~ like someone suggested earlier), correct?

Comment: You sir, are a God among men when it comes to this sort of thing.

Comment: @PaulSkinner Yes, that'll make a backup with a `~` appended at the end of the original filename, like emacs-style backup files.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is good for this type of processing if you have that installed. You could do a little "do .. until" loop that exits once it finds a line with non-whitespace characters. Off the top of my head:

```
do {

  s/^\s$//;

} until ( /^\S/ );
```

(But verify those regular expressions do what you want them to first!)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 find /path/to/root/directory -type f -exec tr -d '\012' {} \;
```

where /path/to/root/directory is the top-level path where looked for all files to remove all occurrences.

Comment: That removes all `\f` from the file. The OP only wants the ones at the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the Linefeeds are only in the first, say, 10 lines, then you can change the SED command so that it only operates on the first ten lines.  That's the `1,10` below.

```
xargs sed -i -e "1,10s/\012//g"
```